# Reorder the contents of my string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dataframe

This is the sample dataframe which I managed to make for better understanding.

`import pandas as pd`

`import numpy as np`

`df = pd.DataFrame([["{postal2:express}", "{postal1:regular}", "{postal4:slow}", "{postal3:slow}","{address1:ABC}","{address4:VPN}","{address3:XYZ}","{address2:POL}"],["{postal1:regular}","{postal4:slow}","{address4:VPN}","{address3:XYZ}","{postal3:slow}","{address1:ABC}","{postal2:express}","{address2:POL}"]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])`

However the output which I need should e grouped like in the image:
[targetdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4lqE.png)

Comment: please use the code tags, to formatyour input a bit nicer ("```")

Comment: Also provided us with some of the starting code that you use for a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In that way we know what you did and can help you better.

Comment: @Thymen, it is just a column with multiple rows,
I basically put two rows of that data to help understand.

Comment: Paste the sample dataframe as is. Don't edit.

Comment: You gave us the output that is wrong, and the output you desire. But we are missing the actual code that you used to generate the 'wrong' output, or attempts you have tried. The code that you pasted right now is not directly a dataframe. Please make it easy for us by directly providing the actual df in a copy paste example, not the output.